# How to find out the Google accounts that have answered a Google Form?

Tags: google-account, google-forms

I have created a Google Form, but I have forgotten to add a 'fill in your email address' question. As a result I can not contact the applicants that have already completed the form. Unfortunately I can not resend the form to the applicants and it would be very important to me to find out their email addresses.

Is there any way to find out the google accounts that have completed the form?